# Effectively stopping an NSTimer in Monotouch when new view controller pushed

Tags: c#, ios, multithreading, xamarin.ios, nstimer

I'm developing a survey based app for the iPad using Monotouch and am trying to implement a timer that returns the survey to the first question if someone takes too long to answer (_survey.Timeout).

I'm using the following code within the view controller and this works fine the first time it's fired but it continues looping - so the question is, how do I stop the thread and properly dispose of the timer when the new view controller is pushed so that it effectively restarts from 0 seconds in the new view.

```
/* ViewDidLoad */
if (_survey.CurrentQuestion != 1)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(StartTimer as ThreadStart);
            thread.Start();
        }    

/* ThreadStart */
void StartTimer()
{
        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
        {
            NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(_survey.Timeout, delegate { 
                _survey.CurrentQuestion = 1;
                _survey.Responses.Clear();
                QuestionController qvc = new QuestionController(_survey);
                this.NavigationController.PushViewController(qvc, false);       
            });
            NSRunLoop.Current.Run();
        }
}
```

I know it's probably something stupidly simple but please put me out of my misery!

Comment: Hi Matt, I have to develop also a survey based app for the Ipad using Monotouch and would like to get any advice or guideline on how is the best way to start. Thanks a lot Matt appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CreateScheduledTimer returns an NSTimer. Call `Invalidate` on that object:

```
NSTimer timer;

void StartTimer()
{
    using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
    {
        timer = NSTimer.CreateScheduledTimer(_survey.Timeout, delegate { 
            _survey.CurrentQuestion = 1;
            _survey.Responses.Clear();
            QuestionController qvc = new QuestionController(_survey);
            this.NavigationController.PushViewController(qvc, false);       
        });
        NSRunLoop.Current.Run();
    }
}

void StopTimer ()
{
    timer.Invalidate ();
    timer.Dispose ();
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Rolf, but where do I put the call to StopTimer?

Comment: If you only want the timer to execute once, you can put it in the timer callback, and then call StartTimer just after to create a new timer.

Comment: Ah, it seems the issue was actually that I'd neglected to manually stop the timer when the user answered the question before the timeout. Solved now though, thanks for your help.